# UIToolbar with custom height

Tags: swift

I'm trying trying to change my toolbar that I added Programmatically. but it didn't reflect. so any help
this is my code. and in the viewController I embed the view from UINavigation Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIToolbarDelegate {
  private var toolItems : [UIBarButtonItem] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

    let height: CGFloat = 130
    let bounds = self.navigationController?.toolbar.bounds

    navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/42, green: 0.0/42, blue: 0.0/56, alpha: 1)
    navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 80, width: self.view.frame.width, height: (bounds?.height)! + height)
    navigationController?.toolbar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController?.toolbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (bounds?.height)! + height).isActive = true
    navigationController?.toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let btn_Tracking = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn_Tracking.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon-trackingtabbed@2x"), for: .normal)
    btn_Tracking.sizeToFit()
    let trackingItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn_Tracking)

    ///Sign
    let btn_sign = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn_sign.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon-trackingtabbed@2x"), for: .normal)
    btn_sign.sizeToFit()
    let sginItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn_sign)
    let fixedSpace: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    fixedSpace.width = 10.0
    let flexibleSpace: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    self.toolbarItems = [flexibleSpace,sginItem,flexibleSpace,trackingItem,flexibleSpace]
  }    
}
```

Comment: might you show us the code you are using for adding the `UIToolBar`?

Comment: what do you mean ? I didn't got you

Comment: You said you added the `UIToolBar` "Programmatically", since the code above is not related to such purpose, I would like to see the relevant code.

Comment: I edited the post and putted full code

Comment: I don't see any `UIToolBar` initialization, did you do from the `Storyboard`?

Comment: no, just added     navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

Comment: I see... so just do this: `print(navigationController?.toolbar)` after `isToolbarHidden = false`, what you get?

Comment: Optional(<UIToolbar: 0x7ff0bad12550; frame = (0 623; 375 44); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000003d540>>)